# Tomcat LDAP User Auth

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap, tomcat7

What I need to know: is it possible to authenticate my Tomcat-Users via two completly different Acitve Directories? So that my Tomcat looks for the credentials in both ADs at the same time? And if its possible, how? Can I just configure them as two realms?

What I tried: Googled a lot, didn't get a satisfying answer. Sadly I do not have a testing environment

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Define a JAAS realm, with two LoginModules, either of which is 'sufficient', in the language of JAAS. Each LoginModule should talk to one of the AD servers. There's quite a bit in this, but it's doable.

Comment: Good Sir, many thanks for your answer. So it is not possible to just define a second JNDI realm?
I allready have one AD connected via JNDI realm and I hoped it would be possible to connect the second one in the same manner.

Comment: @th1nk Good question. I don't know. I did it the way I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You should try "Using CombinedRealm gives the developer the ability to combine multiple Realms of the same or different types."

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm

Comment: Dear Sir, after just reading through the whole realm-howto I also think this is the most promising way. This should allow me to use a second JNDI realm, so I can just copy the existing realm and change the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a forest or the hosts have a cross-realm trust, use Kerberos:
http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/