# Java Active Directory Login Without Domain

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

We have a couple of sites that use our company AD.
Currently in order to login we have to use the following

> iuser\userid

with the code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    config.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    config.put("java.naming.provider.url", ldapUrl);
    config.put("java.naming.security.authentication", "simple");
    config.put("java.naming.security.principal", "iuser\\" + username);
    config.put("java.naming.security.credentials", password);

InitialDirContext dirCxt = new InitialDirContext(config);
```

However when we go to search the AD we can only use just the userid

```
SearchControls cons = new SearchControls();
cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> resultsEnum =
                derek.search("dc=iuser,dc=example,dc=example,dc=com", "(&(objectCategory=user)(cn={0}))", new Object[] {username}, cons);
```

When we try to create the InitialDirContext without putting the domain first then we get User not found response

Is there a way of creating the InitialDirContext without having to put our domain infront of the username?

Answer (score 0):

While I would recommend you to rather use [Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757053/696632). You should try the global catalog and not use `commonName` but rather a unique attribute like `userPrincipalName` or `aAMAccountName`.